# Spring AMQP application configuration from XML to Java

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm struggling with rewriting RabbitMQ application configuration from XML to Java. Sadly once the code is executed, quite general error appears:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: 
Failed to invoke target method 'receiveMessage' with 
argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@3bd0e47}]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.MessageListener.receiveMessage([B)
```

Application works if I base my configuration on XML, listed below.
I tried to rewrite it, basing on Spring Integration, AMQP, Rabbit documentation. Nevertheless, spring configuration documentation is mostly xml based, hence my question.

XML conf:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="mycompany-host"
                               username="mycompany-username"
                               password="mycompany-password"
                               virtual-host="mycompany-vhost"/>

    <rabbit:template id="mycompany-template" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:admin id="admin" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

 <!-- ##### -->

    <rabbit:queue id="queue-id" name="queue-name" declared-by="admin"/>

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="mycompany-incoming-events" declared-by="admin">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="queue-name" key="" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>


 <!-- ##### -->


    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="mycompany-channel"
                                      queue-names="queue-name" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <int:chain input-channel="mycompany-channel">
        <int:transformer>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.MyCompanyParser"/>
        </int:transformer>
        <int:filter expression="payload.header != null"/>
        <int:transformer>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.MyCompanyHeaderEnricher"/>
        </int:transformer>
        <int:recipient-list-router>
            <int:recipient channel="dataSubmittedChannel"/>
        </int:recipient-list-router>
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="dataSubmittedChannel">
        <int:filter expression="headers.mycompany_enriched_header.name().equals('MY_COMPANY_CONSTRAINT')" />
        <int:service-activator>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.MessageListener"/>
        </int:service-activator>
    </int:chain>

</beans>
```

Java listener:

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {

    public void receiveMessage(final MyCompanyParsedType msg){
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
    }
}
```

After some rewriting I managed to came up with this Java based configuration:

```
import com.nxcs3.gamefetcher.configuration.SampleConfiguration;
import com.nxcs3.gamefetcher.listener.GameMessageListener;
import nxcs.drept.nxcs2events.EventHeadersEnricher;
import nxcs.drept.nxcs2events.EventParser;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCompanySpringBootApp {

    public static final String MESSAGE_QUEUE = "queue-name";
    public static final String MESSAGE_EXCHANGE = "mycompany-incoming-events";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyCompanySpringBootApp.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange(){
        return new DirectExchange(MESSAGE_EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue(){
        return new Queue(MESSAGE_QUEUE, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange()).with(MESSAGE_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(MessageListener receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(){
        return f -> f.log()
                .transform(new MyCompanyParser())
                .filter("payload.header != null")
                .transform(new MyCompanyHeaderEnricher())
                .filter("headers.mycompany_enriched_header.name().equals('MY_COMPANY_CONSTRAINT')");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(MESSAGE_QUEUE);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }
}
```

I supply connection details through yaml.
As I mentioned previously, I clearly miss something. 
Any ideas where did the configuration went wrong?

**Added section after comments, proposed solution:**

So I removed `MessageListenerAdapter` and replaced it using `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter` and `@ServiceActivator`

Result would look like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCompanySpringBootApp {

    public static final String MESSAGE_QUEUE = "queue-name";
    public static final String MESSAGE_EXCHANGE = "mycompany-incoming-events";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyCompanySpringBootApp.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange(){
        return new DirectExchange(MESSAGE_EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue(){
        return new Queue(MESSAGE_QUEUE, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange()).with(MESSAGE_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter 
channelAdapter(SimpleMessageListenerContainer container){
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter amqpInboundChannelAdapter = new 
AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(container);
        amqpInboundChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("adapter");
        return amqpInboundChannelAdapter;
    }

 @Bean
public MessageListener handler(){
    return new MessageListener();
}


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(){
        return f -> f.log()
                .transform(new MyCompanyParser())
                .filter("payload.header != null")
                .transform(new MyCompanyHeaderEnricher())
                .filter("headers.mycompany_enriched_header.name().equals('MY_COMPANY_CONSTRAINT')");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(MESSAGE_QUEUE);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }
}
```

and listener:

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "adapter")
    public void receiveMessage(final MyCompanyParsedType msg){
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
    }
}
```

Which brings us a little bit closer, because messages are being accepted and processed inside of `receiveMessage` method.
However somehow coming messages do not pass through `IntegrationFlow` filters. Messages appear to be totally random. **I added imports**

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageListenerAdapter` uses a `SimpleMessageConverter` by default.

And its logic is based on the presence of the `contentType` property.

According to your error, that sounds like there is no this property in the consumed message, therefore it falls back to the `message.getBody()`, which is `byte[]` anyway.

You may consider to specify a desired `MessageConverter` into that `MessageListenerAdapter`, e.g. `SerializerMessageConverter` with the `ignoreContentType = true`.

Comment: I just translated following xml example which works correctly. I repeated every single line and tried to reflect it within java conf. There is some config missing and I am not able to find one. Do you have example which could back my question?

Comment: Well, there is no `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` in your XML sample. It is based on the Spring Integration's `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` which is `Amqp.inboundAdapter()` equivalent. And there is no any `MessageListener` in your XML at all. Sorry, that hard to help if you step aside from the task.

Comment: Your Spring AMQP part is fully correct though. I think the problem that you are missing Java DSL for Spring Integration AMQP: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#_configuring_with_the_java_dsl_2

Comment: What you try to propose, is the fact, that there is something missing in xml configuration?
Or I should focus on implementing Amqp.inboundAdapter in my java conf?

Comment: The problem that you show not equivalent peaces of code. Maybe you can share a simple project on GH and I'll try to convert it for your to Java DSL?

Comment: Error from question is followed by Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompanyr.MessageListener.receiveMessage([B)

Comment: Sadly cannot,  that's all I can put publicly on internet.
I Hope Gary Russel will take a look on that question.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell

Comment: OK. There is really something else you don't show. And error says that your AMQP message doesn't supply `contentType` property. That's what I explained you. Right, it isn't related to the code, but let's concentrate then on one problem per cycle! Since no code, then not too much help

Comment: I have nothing else to paste here. It is all which is related to problem. This code itself run on xml example. Does not work with Java conf. I double checked in one minute ago.

Comment: Your conversion is incorrect. In the XML case, Spring Integration is used to invoke your listener. In the Java case, you are using a `MessageListenerAdapter`.  For equivalence, use an `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter` and use a `@ServiceActivator` to invoke your "listener". See [documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_2) for both Java and DSL examples. In your case, just add `@ServiceActivator` to your `receiveMessage` method.

Comment: So I removed `MessageListenerAdapter` and added:
`@Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter channelAdapter(SimpleMessageListenerContainer container){
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter amqpInboundChannelAdapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(container);
        amqpInboundChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName("adapter");
        return amqpInboundChannelAdapter;
    }`

and also:
`@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "adapter")
    public MessageListener handler(){
        return new GameMessageListener();
    }`

Which results in: <next comment>

Comment: The possibility to accept messages! Debugger confirms that execution goes inside of `receiveMessage` method.
However accepted messages are completely random, seems like it does not go through Integration Flow

`@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(){
        return f -> f.log()
                .transform(new MyCompanyParser())
                .filter("payload.header != null")
                .transform(new MyCompanyHeaderEnricher())
                .filter("headers.mycompany_enriched_header.name().equals('MY_COMPANY_CONSTRAINT')");
    }`

Comment: The code in the comments is not readable. Sorry, we can't help this way

Comment: I will move comment content inside of my question body, 3 min

Comment: Too much problems per inconvenient SO chat

Comment: Maybe you can jump into gitter https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-integration and we will try to solve your problem with small steps?

Comment: Edited initial question, added your proposition guys which brings us a little bit closer

Comment: Please, move `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "adapter")` into the `MessageListener.receiveMessage()`. It's not going work properly: the `@ServiceActivator` can be on `@Bean` only if it is a `MessageHandler`, but it's not in your case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

Comment: After proposed changes result is exactly the same. Coming messages do not pass through IntegrationFlow filters. Messages appear to be totally random

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169378/discussion-between-krzakov-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: No, come to us tomorrow, please, in the mentioned Gitter channel. The SO chat is inconvenient.